# Error displaying the autonumber field from a ResultSet

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, resultset

The movie which is inputted is successfully saved to moviesTbl table but then when I try to display the autonumber field 'MovieID' I retrieve errors.

```
public void updateMovies(String update, String title, java.sql.Date releaseDate, String genre) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = dc.DatabaseConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(update); //the insert statement is prepared 
    statement.setString(1, title); //each attribute is set individually
    statement.setDate(2, releaseDate);
    statement.setString(3, genre);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    statement.close();
    ResultSet ID = dc.query("Select * from moviesTbl where title = " + title + " and genre = " + genre + " and releaseDate = " + releaseDate); //a ResultSet is prepared for the ID of the movie 
    while(ID.next()) { //the ResultSet is prepared for display
        int movieID = ID.getInt("MovieID");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The movie's ID is " + movieID + ". Please record it on the DVD for future reference.");
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HARRY
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:462)
at movierentalstore.DatabaseConnection.query(DatabaseConnection.java:63)
at movierentalstore.QueryingTheDatabase.updateMovies(QueryingTheDatabase.java:181)
at movierentalstore.MovieRentalStore1.<init>(MovieRentalStore1.java:77)
at movierentalstore.MovieRentalStore1.main(MovieRentalStore1.java:25)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HARRY
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:460)
      ... 4 more
      Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HARRY
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: Please provide the errors and the stacktrace. We don't have a magic crystall ball to foresee what's happening in your environment.

Comment: Your main error: *net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HARRY*. Seems like you have a query like this: `SELECT* FROM HARRY`. Debug through your code to check if you have something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC uses the database engine's capability to return the generated key.
This prevents the need to do it database vendor specific, and most important:
you get the correct ID, even if two peoply do the same database insert at the same time.

```
try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO moviesTbl  (title, ...) VALUES(?, ? ...)")) {
    stm.setString(1, title);
    stm.setString(2, ...);
    ...
    int updateCount = stm.executeUpdate();
    if (updateCount != 0) {
        try (ResultSet genKeys = stm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (genKeys.next()) { // At most 1 record inserted
                // Normally only one key generated per record.
                int id = genKeys.getInt(0);
                ...
            }
        } // Close result set.
    }
} // Closes stm
```

It is a bit verbose, but theoretically you could have some statement with several records, and per record more than 1 generated key.

**The error could stem from the SELECT where the string constants are not between apostrophes (`'`).** Should have been a PreparedStatement too.

Comment: It was true that I was missing the apostrophes and it did work a little more when I added them in. But, I understand that the getGeneratedKeys() method is a much better way for retrieving the primary key (as it completely uniquely identifies the field). 

Although, when I tried it, and I added in a println to display the key, no errors occurred, but the key was not displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Yohi use `PreparedStatement`s for your `SELECT` queries as well. Probably the class of `dc` provides a method where it can execute a query and pass the parameters in an array or something like that.

Comment: Check whether `updateCount` indeed is not zero. Then whether `genKeys.next()` holds; it might just be that the java MS Access driver could not implement that functionality. As MS Access is not really a good database, maybe you could switch to h2 databasse or so.