# Cannot insert a data to table on servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm tring read the data from reg form and insert it to a db, this part should add the item but it doesn't work. Do you have a recommendation ?

```
 if ("/RegForm".equals(url)) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    } else if ("/Signup".equals(url)) {
        //dddddddd
        try {
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deneme", "root", "");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Execute SQL query
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO students (name, id, `gpa`) VALUES ("+ request.getParameter("st_name") +","+ request.getParameter("st_id") +","+ request.getParameter("st_gpa") +")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);

        } catch (Exception se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/register_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

ps: i'm really not familiar using java in web apps, just trying to learn.

Comment: Can you tell more on what u get exception. How u get st_name,st_id,st_gpa.
Please provide the more description. so we can help.

Comment: Missing apostrophes, but really read first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247569/error-displaying-the-autonumber-field-from-a-resultset/25248455#25248455 and http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: It's apostrophes ! you were right thanks.

Comment: You're trying to insert strings as integers. Even after you add the single quotes, this is liable to sql injection or simply breaking on a string like `o'brien`.

Comment: Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)  insted of statement to avoid these kind of errors also you can avoid SQL Injection

Comment: @heceis your problem solved?

Comment: yeah i put apostrophes and its solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [preparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection), your code should be:

```
if ("/RegForm".equals(url)) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    } else if ("/Signup".equals(url)) {
        //dddddddd
        try {
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deneme", "root", "");

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


            // Execute SQL query
            String  insert= "INSERT INTO students (name, id, `gpa`) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insert);
            //Assume all paramaters as String
            preparedStatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("st_name"));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, request.getParameter("st_id"));
            preparedStatement.setString(3, request.getParameter("st_gpa"));
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/register_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

You can check here for more [detailed example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any specific error you are getting..?
Or do one thing just print the count like this:

```
int count= stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

Check the value of count. put some S.O.P inside else condition and cross check whether it is going to that section or not.

Comment: it was aphostropes, sorry for misleading.